# how to add delete option in dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, widget, delete-row, bloc

I'm working in small project. For Login, I need to save URL in shared preferences so that next time user can select it in dropdown. I need to keep delete option in that dropdown to delete old URL. How to do?

code:

```
 if (getALLURL.isNotEmpty) ...[
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: baseurl.isNotEmpty ? baseurl : null,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                  underline: SizedBox(),
                  focusColor: AppColors().linenDark,
                  elevation: 1,
                  enableFeedback: true,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                      fontSize: AppSizes().paraLarge16,
                      color: AppColors().linenDark,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
                    color: AppColors().linenMedium,
                  ),
                  items: getALLURL.map((String item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      child: Text(item),
                      value: item,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) async {
                    setState(() {
                      baseurl = value!;
                      print(baseurl);
                    });
                    await Prefs().setBaseURLLogin(baseurl);
                  },
                  hint: Text("Select item"),
                ),
                //IconButton(onPressed: onDelete, icon: Icon(Icons.delete))
              ],
```

Now I'm only used text in menuitems, how to add delete in it. Can I delete particular value in shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

> Can I delete particular value in shared preferences

Yes, you can write new value over the old one with same key.

> Now I'm only used text in menuitems, how to add delete in it

i don't think it could support that directly . Even if it , i recommended you to use instead way for delete option such as any position of the screen.

Comment: is there any way to add delete option in dropdown menu?

Comment: No :) @Mohan ...

Comment: you welcome . if do you think it was helpful answer please mark it and vote Mohan